# ACL: How to prevent specific user to access certain directory that is world-accessible?

Tags: linux, filesystems, acl

I know that with the following command I could give a user the right read/write and enter a certain directory:

```
setfacl -m u:user:rwx /dir/
```

I want to do quite the opposite in fact: The directory is world-accessible, but only one certain user should be banned with the help of ACL. How could I achieve that?

Comment: The  -x (--remove) and -X (--remove-file) options remove ACL entries. I want to add a ACL to prevent User X to enter DIR Y, which is world-accessible.

Comment: `setfacl -m u:user:--- /dir/`?